# Internal mail flow between two sites

Tags: exchange-2007

I have two sites:

- DATACENTER
- HQ

Exchange Roles:

- HQ: Mailbox Store, Client Access, Hub Transport
- DATACENTER: Client Access, Hub Transport

Here is the basic mail flow requirements:

Outgoing Email:

`HQ > DATACENTER > INTERNET`

Incoming Email:

`INTERNET > DATACENTER > HQ`

I've been banging my head on this setting up different Hub Transport rules, etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the path to the datacenter?  Is it over the internet?

Comment: The connection was over a VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that our Hub Transport role at the DATACENTER wasn't allowing anonymous access. This prevented me from recieving mail from our spam gateway.